Proving $\lim_{n\to\infty}2^n\sqrt{2-2\sqrt{1-(\frac{1}{2})^{2n}}}=1$
Here an interesting link between square roots and the constant 1:
$\lim_{n\to\infty}2^n\cdot\sqrt{2-2\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2n}}}=1$.
I'm stuck, I need a hint if possible to prove this formula.

Just let $x=2^n$. Also consider using $(a+\sqrt b)(a-\sqrt b)=a^2-b$.

Thank you William.

First notice that:
$$2^n \cdot \sqrt{2 - 2\sqrt{1 - \left(\frac12\right)^{2n}}} = \sqrt{2^{2n}\cdot\left(2 - 2\sqrt{1 - 2^{-2n}}\right)}$$
Thus, we can just compute:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}2^{2n} \cdot \left(2 - 2\sqrt{1 - 2^{-2n}}\right)$$
And take the square root of the result. This limit is much easier to handle. Now make $n$ a real variable, so that we can compute the limit of the function instead of the sequence (they'll be equal). We can now substitute $m=2^{-2n}$ and rewrite it as:
$$\lim_{m\to0}\frac{2 - 2\sqrt{1 - m}}{m}$$
That is easily done using l'Hôpital's rule. The derivative of the numerator approaches 1, as well as that of the denominator. So the limit can be evaluated by direct substitution and it's 1.
Of course, taking the square root will also evaluate 1, that is the final result.

Please do not answer questions without context. It goes agains the rules of the site. See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508
